# Spring : Always say forbidden - Status 403

Tags: java, spring, authentication, authorization

I have configured all the settings for my spring project, but when I try to login in to the application, it says for each request that

```
"The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it."
```

Initially I tried to implement JDBC Authentication, (you can see that I am using the Datasource in my code). But then I tried with in memory authentication too, in both cases, I am unable to access the resources.

Below is my spring config file,

```
package com.nobalg.config;

import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.nobalg")
@PropertySource("classpath:persistence-mysql.properties")
public class AppConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource secureDataSource(){
        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        try {
            //Datasource
            dataSource.setDriverClass(env.getProperty("jdbc.driver"));
            dataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
            dataSource.setUser(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
            dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));

            //Connection polling
            dataSource.setInitialPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("connection.pool.initialPoolSize")));
            dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("connection.pool.maxPoolSize")));
            dataSource.setMinPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("connection.pool.minPoolSize")));
            dataSource.setMaxIdleTime(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("connection.pool.maxIdleTime")));
        } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

Dispatcher Servlet Initializer file

```
package com.nobalg.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class MvcSpringInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Class[]{AppConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

}
```

Spring security configuration file :

```
package com.nobalg.config;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        //auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource);
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("Nobal").password("test@123").authorities("MANAGER");
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/loginPage")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/loginProcessing")
                    .usernameParameter("username")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .permitAll();
    }


}
```

Spring security initializer file

```
package com.nobalg.config;

import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;


public class SpringSecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

The one and only controller

```
package com.nobalg.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

@Controller
public class MainContoller {

    @GetMapping("/loginPage")
    public String showLoginForm(){
        return "login";
    }


}
```

and the login page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form:form method="POST" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/loginProcessing">
<p>Enter Username : <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username"></p>
<p>Enter Password : <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password"></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="LOG IN"></p>
</form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this as your form field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

Or if you want other approach with  [Spring Security JSP tag library](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/taglibs.html#the-csrfinput-tag):

Optionally you can disable csrf, which is enabled by default:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
}
```

## Edit1

Add this bean with passwordEncoder.

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

And set password encoder to auth:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.passwordEncoder(this.passwordEncoder());
}
```

## Edit2

Change `.loginProcessingUrl("/loginProcessing")` which needs `UserDetailsService` to `.defaultSuccessUrl("/")`

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I am already using spring's <form:form> tag, Is it not doing the same as you suggested?

Comment: Your form has no included csrf token.

Comment: Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39407555/681929)

Comment: Please try to disable csrf for a while and test it, and let me know. I will try to find out what happening then.

Comment: It says,internal error, no password encoder mapped, for id null

Comment: You can use "{noop}yourpassword" instead of implementing password encoder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168487/discussion-between-jacek-kulis-and-nobalg).

Comment: Thanks for the vital help, but its weird issue now, Now sometimes, on click of login, it is bypassing even wrong username passwords